# What is the actual class of NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, inheritance, nsarray

Please consider the following piece of code:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray array];

Class class      = [array class];
Class superclass = [array superclass];

NSLog(@"Class %@", class); // __NSArrayI, ok
NSLog(@"Superclass %@", superclass); // NSArray, why? why not NSObject?
```

When printing array's superclass I expected to see `NSObject`, but it prints `NSArray`. Actually I expected to see `NSArray` when printing array's class. Why it works this way? Can anybody explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The structure of `NSArray` is more complicated than just simple inheritance from `NSObject`, because `NSArray` is a *class cluster*. You can find more about class clusters at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html

Answer (score 0):

If you nslog superclass its print NSObject

```
Class superclass = [NSArray superclass];
```

Comment: yes, because superclass class method is define in NSObject class.